# Is a string less bytes than a number?

Tags: node.js, audio, optimization, base64, pcm

I am creating a project for streaming microphone audio PCM data to play on another browser and I am currently done the streaming part and am looking to some sort of optimization as I am sending a buffer that is 8192 long.

I saw in some very few places where encoding the buffer data of the audio to `Base64` can help optimization, and I was wondering why?

Lets say one of the floats in a buffer is `-0.00009942707401933149`. Is that less bytes than what it is in Base64? (`LTAuMDAwMDk5NDI3MDc0MDE5MzMxNDk=`) And if so, why?

Also, I was wondering whether I am supposed to post this question here on Stack Overflow or the [Computer Science](https://cs.stackexchange.com/) section.

Comment: I think most modern browsers can work with the raw binary data, so why bother encoding/decoding?

Comment: Its not because of the browsers, its because of the bandwidth.

Comment: If bandwidth is a concern, have you looked into using an efficient codec instead of transmitting raw/uncompressed audio data? I've used opus before.

Comment: @mscdex I have looked into Opus, but there just hasn't been any specific documents on how to turn raw/uncompressed audio buffers into opus and if even the browser would be able to do it fast enough for streaming. And I am not the greatest coder so I don't know where to start by my self (which is why I am here).